# How to track what mails are sent or pending in laravel jobs (queue)?

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, queue, jobs

I have implemented jobs already just i want to figure out how can i know what mails are sent or pending in queue. I wanna display sent or pending mails on my view.

I am using laravel 5.8 with php version 7.3

This is my env file configurations for mail and queue.

QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io

MAIL_PORT=25

MAIL_USERNAME=**********

MAIL_PASSWORD=**********

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what queue driver do you use

Comment: Hi @Ersoy, I have added the env file details. I am using smtp mail driver and queue connection is database.